# нужна помощь хочу сравнить строки оператором &&(и) в C++ но компилятор(Visual Studio 2017) не запускает программы

Tags: c++

компилятор пишет E0349 отсутствует оператор && соответствующий этим операндам вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string line1 = "Eroor\n", line2 = "Eroor\n", line3 = "Eroor\n";
cout << "Enter Line1\n";
cin >> line1;
cout << "Enter Line2\n";
cin >> line2;
cout << "Enter Line3\n";
cin >> line3;
if (line1 && line2 < line3) {

}

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

По вашему вопросу непонятно, что вы хотите добиться.

Если проверить, что и `line1`, и `line2` меньше `line3` - то это делается так:

```
if ((line1 < line3) && (line 2 < line3)) {
```

Если что-то иное - поясните, что именно вам нужно...

Comment: Спасибо большое Вы ответили именно на то что я хотел Удачи вам

Comment: Мне нужно было ответить на эти две задачи на первую ответить получилось а вот вторую нет